# How to redirect a WordPress site to a new domain using .htaccess EXCEPT specific pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

My company has moved our primary domain from **architectsmarketing.com** to **archmarketing.org**, and recreated many of the pages using the same WordPress page structure with a new **WordPress** theme.

However, some of the pages are rather complicated, and depend on the functionality of the old theme, so we'd prefer to leave these pages for now on the old site.

We're using `.htaccess` to do a `301 Redirect` for the site, which works nicely:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://archmarketing.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Since we want to be able to access the back end, I added a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-admin|wp-login|wp-content|wp-includes|dap) [NC]
```

To access site pages normally (without redirects) for comparison with the new site, I sometimes add a condition to exclude my specific IP address, which works perfectly:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^73.222.196.53
```

The tricky part is when I try to keep SOME of the WordPress pages still going to the original site. For example, here is a page URL that I want to access on the old site:

```
http://architectsmarketing.com/petrie-method/optin-1/
```

I've tried using the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(petrie-method).*$
```

This does match the page and exclude it from the RewriteRule, but it doesn't allow the page URL to be resolved properly. Instead, that URL redirects to the root of the new site.

So to sum up, my current code (without the IP exclusion) that doesn't quite work is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-admin|wp-login|wp-content|wp-includes|dap) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(petrie-method).*$
RewriteRule (.*) http://archmarketing.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> NOTE: This all goes above the standard WordPress Rewrite block.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance. I have been researching `.htaccess` rules for hours, and tried dozens of code combinations without success.